# How update template radio button

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there an elegant way of updating 'description' using JQuery?

```
<div>
    <div class="radio">
        <label>
            <input name="somename" type="radio">description
        </label>
    </div>
    <div class="well">
        <div class="line">Something</div>
        <div class="line">Something else</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I had tried text('new description') on the label but then the input is removed as well. Is there a solution without having serialized html in my javascript?

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/t12gvzj0/)

What I'm trying to achieve is to have a template radio button in the source html which I can clone, update and append dynamically. I'm not sure if there is a better pattern out there to achieve a dynamic list of choices.

Comment: How about wrapping the text after the input in `<span>` tags?

Comment: @chrisvdb If you can't change the markup you could do this. https://jsfiddle.net/fxL0xyw1/    I will say that I don't really like this solution though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you are: just use `label for`

```js
$('#somelabel').text('new description');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <div class="radio">
    <input name="somename" type="radio">
    <label id='somelabel' for="somename">description</label>
  </div>
  <div class="well">
    <div class="line">Something</div>
    <div class="line">Something else</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I'm able to change the HTML, so this solution works perfectly. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Surround it by a span and then update the text in the span. Like so

```
<div>
    <div class="radio">
        <label>
            <input name="somename" type="radio"><span id="needsUpdate">description</span>
        </label>
    </div>
    <div class="well">
        <div class="line">Something</div>
        <div class="line">Something else</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

then javascript

```
$('#needsUpdate').text('new description');
```

Comment: After writing this I saw @j08691 suggested it before me in a comment. He should post it as an answer and it should be accepted.

Comment: Clever solution... should have thought this! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could use `this.nodeType === 3`, but I wouldn't recommend it unless you really cannot change the HTML to wrap the text in a span.

```js
$('label')
  .contents()
  .filter(function() {
    return this.nodeType === 3 && $(this).index() != 0;
  }).replaceWith('New text');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
    <div class="radio">
        <label>
            <input name="somename" type="radio">description
        </label>
    </div>
</div>
```